# WordPress - How to attain rapid speeds akin to python

Tags: wordpress, performance, laravel, nosql

I built an app using wordpress, and someone rebuilt the same app with django. The database work is way faster with the django app. Using the standard MySQL database in wordpress seems to be way too slow since I need to do thousands of queries at once.

Any tips on how to do rapid database interactions using wordpress? Someone recommended FireBase to me, although I have yet to learn what it is. Could I create a NoSQL database and interact with it?

Comment: You can just change the driver of db if your migrations can create all the data and test it. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database No official nosql driver yet, you have github: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Comment: you can do anything you want really but wp natively uses mysql so it would be a lot of work to customize for a different db, but the issue with wp is the number of queries involved in a page load. You can use caching obviously to improve this then measure your custom mysql. You havent mentioned what activity you are doing on the db but there are volumes of different uses and setups for all types of dbs

Comment: Well one activity involves inserting over 10,000 rows into the database, so inserting these into the wordpress MySQL database can be extremely slow. Then another task involves getting hundreds of rows, with two tables joined from the database and this seems really slow too.

Comment: the 10000 will be slow with most db depending on amount of memory involved. But im assuming this is a set up process rather than a normal process? For the read joins are considerably slower, if the data is not unique you can cache but it seems a lot of data for internet speeds which i would say is more of a sticking point? have you measured the processes using micro time? There are optimizations for read only if you google it.